# Getting percent of height, vertical volume slider

Tags: actionscript-3, slider

ok I am having a brain fart right now and can't think straight. I've done this many times before.

I am making a vertical volume slider. The top of my slider track is at -80 and the bottom is -16. So my volume handle can slide between -80 and -16 on the Y axis.

-48 is basically 50%. I can't for the life of me figure out this percentage right now, can someone give me a little math help. I took math in summer school all 3 years of high school for a reason :P

Comment: I chose taskinoor's answer because it doesn't need to use the `Math` class, but both of these solutions worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
max = -80
min = -16
so total points in range = 64
so 50% of total = 64 / 2 = 32
```

Now starts moving up from -16. You get -48 when you move 32 (50%) points up.

So the percent for any value `v` (in positive) in range 16 to 80 is:

```
percent = (v - 16) / 64 * 100
```

For this example: `(48 - 16) / 64 * 100 = 50`

Comment: thank you taskinoor, this works as well...now who to accept, eeek

Answer (score 1):

Negative numbers confuse me on this sort of thing, but that's what spreadsheets and trial & error are for.

If I read the question right, you know -48 is 50%, and you'd like to know the percentages for other inputs (e.g., -12, -60, etc)

1. Remove the bias so our range is 0 .. max
2. Divide that by the max to get the percentage
3. Take the absolute value

if v is your input value (-48), then `p = Math.abs((v+16)/64)` where "+16" is just subtracting your lower bound (-16), and "64" is the absolute value of the upper bound minus the lower bound.

Put another way,

```
var lower:int = -16;
var upper:int = -80;
var v:int = -32;
var p:Number = Math.abs((v - lower) / (Math.abs(upper - lower));
```

I haven't tested this - no compiler here.

Comment: excellent, both of these solutions work. The negative numbers confuse the crap outa me too.